# Simplify/Enhance Python Filtering Algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, sorting

I'm looking for a way to identify the dist.xml files that are in the top most directory.

Example, I have this list of directory listing,

```
/opt/pictures/dist.xml
/opt/docs_old/dist.xml
/opt/public/dist.xml
/opt/documents/server/dist.xml
/opt/documents/dist.xml
/opt/documents/web/dist.xml
/opt/documents/class/dist.xml
/opt/documents/lessons/1/dist.xml
/opt/documents/lessons/2/dist.xml
/opt/documents/lessons/3/dist.xml
/opt/documents/lessons/4/dist.xml
/opt/documents/lessons/5/dist.xml
/opt/music/service/day/dist.xml
/opt/music/service/week/dist.xml
/opt/music/service/month/dist.xml
/opt/music/service/month/1/dist.xml
/opt/music/service/month/2/dist.xml
```

and I'm looking to have this output instead,

```
/opt/pictures/dist.xml
/opt/docs_old/dist.xml
/opt/public/dist.xml
/opt/documents/dist.xml
/opt/music/service/day/dist.xml
/opt/music/service/week/dist.xml
/opt/music/service/month/dist.xml
```

I have the following code that appears to do the job, wondering if there's anyway to speed up or make clear the code,

```
from pathlib import Path

paths = ['/opt/pictures/dist.xml', '/opt/docs_old/dist.xml', '/opt/public/dist.xml', '/opt/documents/server/dist.xml', '/opt/documents/dist.xml', '/opt/documents/web/dist.xml', '/opt/documents/class/dist.xml', '/opt/documents/lessons/1/dist.xml', '/opt/documents/lessons/2/dist.xml', '/opt/documents/lessons/3/dist.xml', '/opt/documents/lessons/4/dist.xml', '/opt/documents/lessons/5/dist.xml', '/opt/music/service/day/dist.xml', '/opt/music/service/week/dist.xml', '/opt/music/service/month/dist.xml', '/opt/music/service/month/1/dist.xml', '/opt/music/service/month/2/dist.xml']

paths = list(set(paths))
paths_folder = [str(Path(p).parent) for p in paths]

to_remove = []
for idx, val in enumerate(paths_folder):
  for b in Path(val).parents:
    if str(b) in paths_folder:
      to_remove.append(idx)

paths_folder = [i for j, i in enumerate(paths_folder) if j not in to_remove]

paths_folder = [p + '/dist.xml' for p in paths_folder]

print(paths_folder)
```

Comment: The *wanted output* is not a different sorting of the actual output. What do you mean by your title?

Comment: Also, would you explain in words what is the rationale for getting that output from the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach that may be cleaner since it avoids index-tracking, etc.:

First sort all the `path_folders` so that it's top-most folders first. Then check for each parent folders' presence in the "top folders" list, as you did but using the [`all()` built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all), which is true only after the condition is true for all items. Then immediately add it to the final folder list, since anything *following* that item is either a different folder or a child of the current one; because of the sort done before.

```
from pathlib import Path

paths = ['/opt/pictures/dist.xml', '/opt/docs_old/dist.xml', ...]  # as above
path_folders = sorted(set(Path(p).parent for p in paths),
                      key=lambda x: (len(x.parts), x))    # is now sorted tops-first

top_folders = []
for folder in path_folders:
    if all(parent not in top_folders for parent in folder.parents):
        top_folders.append(folder)

top_dists = [f / 'dist.xml' for f in top_folders]  # can use '/' with Path objs!
print(top_dists)
```